# Jenkins pipeline : using variable created in shell 1, in shell 2

Tags: shell, variables, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, environment

In my pipeline I've 2 stages, and they both call a different shell script (the way they're called is some custom code as we have different pipelines interacting with each other) :

```
stage('first') {
  steps {
    script {
      stageErrors.add(launchPortalStep.launchStepWithVerification('shell',"chmod +x ./script1.sh && ./script1.sh"))
    }
  }
}
stage('second') {
  steps {
    script {
      stageErrors.add(launchPortalStep.launchStepWithVerification('shell',"chmod +x ./script2.sh && ./script2.sh"))
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is, in script2 I need to use a variable that is set in script1, the only ways I've think of that could work would mean pretty much rewriting everything and that's not a possibility.

Script1 must return either 0 or 1, so it's not possible to return the value and stock in an environment variable that would be then passed as a parameter in script2.
Scripts are also way too long to have them entirely in the pipeline using sh commands (that would be adding at least 700 lines).

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a properties file (it can be even a temp file) to pass the needed variables between the stages.

You should write the needed variables into a properties file (in `VAR=VAL` format) in the `shell` script which is called in `First` step (`sh 'echo "MY_ENV_VAR=test_var" > test.prop'`).

You should read the properties file in the `Second` step with the `readProperties` function which is part of the `Pipeline Utility Steps` plugin `def props = readProperties file: 'test.pro`). Then set the needed variables as environment variables (`env.MY_ENV_VAR = props.MY_ENV_VAR`) so you will be able to use the variables in your second shell script as environment variables (`sh 'echo MY_ENV_VAR = ${MY_ENV_VAR}'`).

**Complete example code:**

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'MISC' }
    stages{
        stage('First'){
            steps {
                sh 'echo "MY_ENV_VAR=test_var" > test.prop'
            }
        }
        stage('Second'){
            steps {
                script {
                    // readProperties is a step in Pipeline Utility Steps plugin
                    def props = readProperties file: 'test.prop'
                    // Assuming the key name is MY_ENV_VAR in properties file.
                    env.MY_ENV_VAR = props.MY_ENV_VAR
                    sh 'echo MY_ENV_VAR = ${MY_ENV_VAR}'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (First)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo MY_ENV_VAR=test_var
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Second)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readProperties
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo MY_ENV_VAR = test_var
MY_ENV_VAR = test_var
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly we don't have the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin installed :( (and I'm not sure the admins will allow it, they don't add stuff unless absolutely required, but I'll ask).
Would it work if the "echo ..." was inside my first shell script ? I'm assuming I'd have to use readProperties right before executing the 2nd script, but do I have to pass the variable as a parameter ?

Comment: Sure, you can write the properties file in your Shell script. Yes, you have to read the properties file (readProperties) before you call the second Shell script and you don't need to pass the variables as parameters, you can use them as Environment variables in your second Shell script.